# Duplicate entry 'ID' for key primary?

Tags: java, mysql, wamp

I have created a database named 'hmdb' and in that database two tables named as table1 and table2 using wamp. Both the tables have ID field as primary key. My java code actually checks first whether the ID is present in table1 or not, if so(actually this is for checking whether it is existing user or not, if not then patient have to first register himself) then it opens a frame where doctor fills patients information with his ID.

The matter of concern is that when the next time doctor fills patients information it says duplicate entry for primary key 'ID'. Here is my question: is there any way that for same 'ID'(primary key) we can insert more than one record in database. In my project it is fairly possible that one patient which have his unique id can visit doctor more than once and since doctor have to record his diagnosis it also imp. to feed details in database. there is also one field named 'date of visit', so I think that I should change primary key for table2 as 'date' (considering one patient can visit doctor max. in a day once only), since date is always different so that I can feed data of same 'ID'. for this  I have a doubt so I want to ask one question: if there are two tables than can we have different primary key for two tables or it is neccessary to have same primary key?

Comment: You should have a third table.  If table1 has patients and patient information, and table2 has doctors and doctor information (your DB name and table names should be more descriptive by the way), then you should also have table3 for "visits" or something where each visit has a unique ID, and the fields include a patient ID, a doctor ID, and maybe some more information on the specific visit.

Answer (score 2):

The solution here is to have a many to many relationship. You need an extra table with a mapping for doctor_id and patient_id.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to create a primary key for visit.  Something like  VISIT_ID.  Because a patient can visit a doctor more than once a day (maybe not usual, but  likely) I would use a manufactured key for VISIT_ID.  Check out autonumbers or auto keys which are common in most DBMS.  They guarantee generation of a unique key for that table.

In the Visit Table, you'd also store foreign keys for doctor and patient that link to the tables containing info on your doc and patient respectively.

Good luck!

Comment: thank you so much i will try it and get you confirmed if worked.

Answer (score 1):

First of all a primary key is to uniquely identify a row. Secondly, create a field called, patient_id and use that one as a patient id rather then the primary key. You can also make this a foreign key from another table which will hold the patient records. And a foreign key will need to be a primary key.